# Unable to access "MyDevice" An operation is already pending error message when mounting SSD

Tags: data-recovery, ssd

My external SSD used to mount seamlessly until a recent incident. Since then, the SSD is recognized by the system, but when trying to mount, the following error message is displayed: "Unable to access "MyDevice" An operation is already pending". `fdisk -l` outputs

```
Device      Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1      34     262177     262144  128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdb2  264192 5860532223 5860268032  2,7T Microsoft basic data

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

The incident was that an ongoing `tar -zvcf`-compression operation on an archive on the SSD was interrupted for unknown reasons .

Some potentially helpful background info: I have a Lenovo X280 with Ubuntu 18.04.

Is there a way to solve this problem or diagnose it better so that the mounting will work again?

**Edit:**

`dmesg` outputs the following:

```
[ 4062.536004] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 4062.536011] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[ 4062.536016] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Invalid field in cdb
[ 4062.536021] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 52 f9 00 00 00 01 00 00
[ 4062.536026] print_req_error: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 479993
[ 4062.536036] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb2, logical block 215801, async page read
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[ 4062.536026] print_req_error: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 479993
[ 4062.536036] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb2, logical block 215801, async page read
```

says basically that your disk drive is dying. Sorry.

---

You may try installing `gddrescue` package containing GNU `ddrescue` program and use it to retrieve as much data as possible from your disk. Refer to its [detailed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html) for more info, or its [basic man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ddrescue).